# Getopt Unix store parameters

Tags: unix, ksh, getopt

I am attempting to store both flags and variables into a script. I will need things like -s for SFTP and -o for the output file. I am attempting to store these into variables to use later. Usage is Script.ksh -o test.txt. the output should be

```
output file is: test.txt
sftpFlag=Y
```

The script contents as follows,

```
args=`getopt -o:-i:-e:-s "$@"`

for arg in $args
do
    case "$arg" in
            o)output=$arg;;
            s)sftpFlag=Y
    esac
done

echo "output file is: "$output
echo "SFTP flag is: "$sftpFlag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getopt -o:-i:-e:-s "$@"` passes options to the getopt command itself, and one of the options `-s` requires a parameter (from manual page):

> ```
> -s, --shell shell
>  Set quoting conventions to those of shell.  If the -s option is not given,
>  the BASH conventions are used.  Valid arguments are currently 'sh' 'bash',
>  'csh', and 'tcsh'.
> ```

The second problem is that you're just assigning to a variable, which means that `$args` gets the value `-o test.txt -s --` (from your example), which gets processed in a single loop.

so rewriting your code:

```
args=`getopt o:i:e:s "$@"`
eval set -- "$args"
while [[ -n $1 ]]
do
    case "$1" in
            -o)output=$2;shift;;
            -s)sftpFlag=Y;;
            --) break;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo "output file is: "$output
echo "SFTP flag is: "$sftpFlag
```

should have the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

The single `s` indicates that it's a flag, while `o:` indicates that it takes an argument. `$OPTARG` will give you the actual argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":so:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    o)
      output=$OPTARG
      ;;
    s) sftpFlag=Y 
       ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
  esac
done

echo "output file is: "$output
echo "SFTP flag is: "$sftpFlag
```

You would call it like `$ test.sh -s -o output.txt`